# Reasons for migrating to a different address on the Ethereum blockchain

Tags: migration

I see a lot of coins have different contract addresses even if they seem to be the exact same coin. This is quite a hassle when I want to analyze the trajectory of firms after their ICOs. Why would be the main reason why a token would migrate to a different address (on the same Ethereum blockchain)?

Answer (score 0):

Since contracts cannot be updated the most likely reason is to fix a bug, or add a new feature.